# Изменить порядок вывода сообщений об ошибках (jQuery Validate)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется форма, которая валидируется при помощи jQuery Validate:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EGXyvr

Код валидации выглядит следующим образом:

```
$("#submit").on("click", function() {
let orderForm = $('#order'),
    successMsg = $(".success");

orderForm.validate({
    rules: {
        fullName: {
            required: true
        },
        eMail: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        question: {
            required: true
        }
    },

    messages: {
        fullName: {
            required: "The name field is required"
        },
        eMail: {
            required: "The e-mail field is required",
            email: "The e-mail address must contain @ symbol"
        },
        question: {
            required: "The question field is required"
        }
    },

    errorElement: "div",

    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertAfter('#submit');
    },

    submitHandler: function() {
        successMsg.show();
        setTimeout(function() {
            location.reload();
        }, 2500);
    }
})
```

});

Как изменить порядок вывода сообщений об ошибках, чтобы сообщение "The name field is required" выводилось первым, а "The question field is required" - последним?

Comment: Изменить порядок добавления полей в orderForm. У Вас, вероятно, fullName стоит после question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
error.insertAfter('#submit');
```

Добавляет сообщения об ошибке после кнопки "Submit". Соответственно, получается инверсия порядка.
Предлагаю, добавить div для вывода сообщений об ошибке. И добавлять их туда через `append`
Вот пример (переделанный ваш)
https://codepen.io/eustatos/pen/MZoexZ?editors=1000

Comment: Все работает, благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Так происходит потому что `insertAfter` вставляет елемент после выбраного вами елемента. То есть, сначала после кнопки `submit` у вас добавилась ошибка для поля `fullName`, затем после кнопки добавилась ошибка для поля `eMail`, подвинув вниз предыдущую ошибку (ошибку для поля `fullName`) и так же произошло с ошибкой для `question`.

Например можно сделать так:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
  document.querySelector('.errors-wrapper').append(error[0]);
}
```

или же:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
  $('.errors-wrapper').append(error);
}
```

Добавив блок с классом `.errors-wrapper` туда, где нужно вывести ошибки.
Или же используйте `insertBefore`